SwiftUI + PencilKit: How to Allow Both Scrolling and Pencil Drawing on an Overlay?
I’m working on a SwiftUI app that displays a day overview with hourly slots in a scrollable view (ScrollView). The goal is to allow users to scroll through the hours with their finger while also being able to write notes on top of this view using the Apple Pencil.
To achieve this, I’ve added a PKCanvasView as an overlay on top of the ScrollView. However, I’m running into an issue where either scrolling works, but Pencil input doesn’t, or Pencil input works, but scrolling through the day overview doesn’t.
Desired Behavior:

Finger input should scroll through the day overview.
Pencil input should be allowed on the overlay to write notes.

What I’ve Tried:

Adding PKCanvasView as an Overlay:
Placed PKCanvasView as an overlay on top of the ScrollView using ZStack.
Set drawingPolicy to .pencilOnly, so that only the Apple Pencil can interact with the PKCanvasView.
Pencil input works, but it completely blocks the underlying ScrollView from detecting finger touches for scrolling.

Embedding PKCanvasView in the ScrollView:
Tried adding PKCanvasView inside the scrollable content, so it would theoretically share the scrollable area.
esult: Scrolling with a finger works, but I can no longer write with the Apple Pencil on the canvas overlay.

Custom Gesture Recognizers:
Attempted using UIGestureRecognizerDelegate to selectively enable touch handling only Result: Either the finger scrolling or the Pencil input was captured, but not both together as needed.


I tried to figure out a minimal reproducible example:
import SwiftUI
import PencilKit

struct DayOverviewView: View {
    let hours = Array(0..<24)
    
    @StateObject private var canvasViewModel = CanvasViewModel()
    @State private var currentHour = Calendar.current.component(.hour, from: Date())

    var body: some View {
        ZStack {
            // Main ScrollView content for day overview
            ScrollViewReader { proxy in
                ScrollView {
                    VStack(spacing: 0) {
                        ForEach(hours, id: \.self) { hour in
                            HStack {
                                Text("\(hour):00")
                                    .frame(width: 60, alignment: .leading)
                                Divider().frame(height: 50)
                                Spacer()
                            }
                            .padding(.vertical, 20)
                            .background(hour == currentHour ? Color.blue.opacity(0.2) : Color.clear) // Highlight current hour
                            .cornerRadius(8)
                            .id(hour)
                        }
                    }
                }
                .onAppear {
                    withAnimation {
                        proxy.scrollTo(currentHour, anchor: .top) // Scroll to the current hour
                    }
                }
            }

            // PKCanvasView overlay, for Pencil input only
            PKCanvasRepresentable(
                canvasView: $canvasViewModel.canvasView,
                toolPicker: $canvasViewModel.toolPicker,
                isToolPickerVisible: $canvasViewModel.isToolPickerVisible
            )
            .background(Color.clear)
            .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.all)
        }
    }
}

// CanvasViewModel to manage PKCanvasView state
class CanvasViewModel: ObservableObject {
    @Published var canvasView = PKCanvasView()
    @Published var toolPicker = PKToolPicker()
    @Published var isToolPickerVisible = false

    init() {
        canvasView.drawingPolicy = .pencilOnly // Allow only Pencil input
        toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: canvasView)
        canvasView.becomeFirstResponder()
    }
}

// PKCanvasRepresentable to wrap PKCanvasView for SwiftUI
struct PKCanvasRepresentable: UIViewRepresentable {
    @Binding var canvasView: PKCanvasView
    @Binding var toolPicker: PKToolPicker
    @Binding var isToolPickerVisible: Bool

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> PKCanvasView {
        canvasView.tool = PKInkingTool(.pen, color: .black, width: 5)
        canvasView.isOpaque = false
        canvasView.backgroundColor = .clear
        canvasView.drawingPolicy = .pencilOnly // Pencil-only input
        return canvasView
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: PKCanvasView, context: Context) {
        if isToolPickerVisible {
            toolPicker.setVisible(true, forFirstResponder: uiView)
            uiView.becomeFirstResponder()
        } else {
            toolPicker.setVisible(false, forFirstResponder: uiView)
            uiView.resignFirstResponder()
        }
    }
}

Any Ideas?
